# Scheduling tweet using oAuth in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter, twitter-oauth, scheduler

I need to create a scheduling system in my mvc project which can schedule the tweets in intervals set by the user. The user logs into the system using twitter and will be provided with a list of contents. This list needs to scheduled for tweeting at intervals specified by the user.

Is there any 3rd party integration which can help me achieve this or any better solution for scheduling the tweets?.

Answer (score 0):

you should use **Quartz.NET Scheduling Framework**

[QUARTZ @ nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/Quartz/)

[QUARTX website](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

I use it and it works fine for me